# Append element to each div in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well, I'm trying to make a logo with `css` and `html` and here is the output:

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czc6bhgw/2/)**

now I want to make this with `jquery` and create all `div` dynamically. this is what I have done so far:

```
var count = 13;
var n = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    n++;
    $('<div class="LogoRow" id="LogoRow-'+n+'"></div>').appendTo('#Logo');
}

$('#Logo .LogoRow:nth-child(odd)').addClass('LogoRowLeft');
$('#Logo .LogoRow:nth-child(even)').addClass('LogoRowRight');

$('.LogoRow').each(function() {
    var count = 8;
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        $(this).append('<span class="LogoTriangle"></span>');
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czc6bhgw/3/)**

I appended 13 `LogoRow` to `#Logo` then 8 `LogoTriangle` to each `LogoRow` but the problem is it should append `LogoTriangle` differently, like this:

```
append 8 `LogoTriangle` to `LogoRow` nth child 1
append 7 `LogoTriangle` to `LogoRow` nth child 2 and 3
append 6 `LogoTriangle` to `LogoRow` nth child 4 and 5
append 5 `LogoTriangle` to `LogoRow` nth child 6 and 7
append 4 `LogoTriangle` to `LogoRow` nth child 8 and 9
append 3 `LogoTriangle` to `LogoRow` nth child 10 and 11
append 2 `LogoTriangle` to `LogoRow` nth child 12 and 13
append 1 `LogoTriangle` to `LogoRow` nth child 14 and 15
```

but i have no idea how can i append an element to another element like this. any suggest?

Comment: Because i want to use css3 animation for this logo @madalinivascu , I already have this logo in svg format.

Comment: @pedram i made a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/czc6bhgw/6/) not so polished but it looks like the css version

Comment: I like your solution @guradio thanks for the reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the initial `count` to `15` in order to get the full triangle.

Move the `count = 8` outside the loop and change the condition to decrease the value like following.

```
count = 8;
$('.LogoRow').each(function(k) {
  console.log(count);
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    $(this).append('<span class="LogoTriangle"></span>');
  }
  if (k == 0 || (k > 0 && k % 2 == 0))
    count--;
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/czc6bhgw/9/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution and help.

Comment: the last piece is missing :)

Comment: @guradio no problem, it was my mistake, `var count = 13;` should change to `var count = 15;`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it by not that simple, but easy to understand way:

```
var count = 15;
var n = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
n++;
$('<div class="LogoRow" id="LogoRow-'+n+'"></div>').appendTo('#Logo');
}

$('#Logo .LogoRow:nth-child(odd)').addClass('LogoRowLeft');
$('#Logo .LogoRow:nth-child(even)').addClass('LogoRowRight');

var appends = {
  1: 8,  2: 7,  3: 7,  4: 6,  5: 6,  6: 5,  7: 5,  
  8: 4,  9: 4,  10: 3,  11: 3,  12: 2,  13: 2,
  14: 1,  15: 1,
};
for(var i in appends){
if(appends.hasOwnProperty(i)){
console.log(i, appends[i]);
    for(var j = 0; j < appends[i]; j++){        
      $('#LogoRow-' + i).append('<span class="LogoTriangle"></span>');
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/czc6bhgw/8/